# get data from third table

Tags: php, sql

Who can help me with my code.
I have 3 tables for example teams, players and lineups.

```
teams
+--+------+
|ID| TEAM |
|1 |Yellow|
|2 |Green |
|3 |Blue  |
|4 |Red   |
+--+------+

Players
+--+------+
|ID| NAME |
|1 |Ben   |
|2 |Mike  |
|3 |Jason |
+--+------+

Lineups
+---+---+
|PID|TID|
|1  |3  |
|2  |1  |
|2  |4  |
|3  |2  | 
+--+----+
```

This is my query

```
SELECT teams.id teamsid, teams.team teamname, lineup.tid
FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN lineup ON (lineup.tid = teams.id AND lineup.pid = 2)
ORDER BY team ASC

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $checked = ($row['tid'] === NULL ? '' : ' checked="checked"');
?>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked; ?>><?php echo $row['teamname']; ?>
</label><?php
}
?>
```

This results

```
<label><input type="checkbox">Blauw</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Geel</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Groen</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Rood</label>
```

So my question is how can I get the playername in the same query from the players table?
For the result above the name has to be "Mike".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join one more time to bring in the `players` table:

```
SELECT 
    t.id teamsid, 
    t.team teamname, 
    l.tid, 
    p.name player_name
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN lineup l ON l.tid = t.id
LEFT JOIN players p ON p.id = l.pid AND p.id = 2
ORDER BY t.team
```

Notes:

- do you really mean `left join`? this will produce empty values in the resultset for teams that have no lineup. I suspect that you want `INNER JOIN`s (and you could move the filer on `p.id = 2` to the `WHERE` clause for more readability
- parentheses around the join conditions are superfluous
- `ASC` is the default `ORDER BY` direction
- table aliases are handy - they make the query shorter to write

Comment: Thanks:) the left join is correct I want fetch the whole teams table. If the result is null the checkbox is not checked if the lineup table has a player and a team the checkbox is checked:)